# How to check programmatically PowerPoint builtin button clicked

Tags: vb.net, vba, office-interop, powerpoint

How could I check if PowerPoint builtin object / button is clicked.

For example : I want to check whether user has clicked in Presenter View on Pen tool , show next slide , hyperlink e.t.c

Does PowerPoint tell us which object is clicked because i found nothing from net although we can determine which shape is clicked which not my need.

Answer (score 0):

No. Nothing in the object model will tell you what tools/menu items/etc. have been clicked.

Comment: then how to perform same thing through another way.

Comment: No idea, I'm afraid.  Perhaps it's not possible.

Comment: Hey @SteveRindsberg. 5 years later, do you know if this has changed? are we able to check by any mean what built-in control has been clicked?

Comment: I don't know of anything that would have changed this @RicardoDiaz

Comment: Thanks! I want to make an add in that allows you to trace which commands you've clickee and write them downso you can make tutorials faster. Eitherway. Thank you for the reponse.

Comment: That would be VERY handy; if you ever work out how to do it, please let us know, @RicardoDiaz.